# Viewing one layer of a pyramid image Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to view the second largest layer from a pyramid image that has already been created. I am finding lots of tutorials on how to create pyramid images, but not so much info on how to specifically view layers of a pre-made image. I was previously trying to use cv2 and matplotlib to view my image, however I was getting some distortion by one of the image edges. The distortion looks almost like white noise on a TV screen.

This is the code I was using to try and view the image:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread('test.tif')
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

The largest image layer is 5367 (width) by 3339 (height) pixels. Any suggestions on how to go about viewing these images would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's a pyramid image? Google is just giving me a lot of images of pyramids.

Comment: @Kevin It is a representation of an image with multiple layers of the same image but of different resolutions [This link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing) has a visual and some general info :)